# Bluetooth only works after sleep

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bluetooth

I am trying to troubleshoot a strange problem but am not quite sure where to start, bluetooth only seems to work after the computer has been put to sleep and woken up again.

If the computer is booted up, or the Bluetooth is toggled on, it is not able to find any devices on the "add Bluetooth device" screen.

Any ideas on where to start?

I am on a Asus N56V Laptop running windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Option A:

1. Through start menu search for 'services'. Once in services scroll down, locate and open 'Bluetooth Support'. Once in Bluetooth support click on the tab that says 'Recovery'.
2. For First and Second Failure it should be set to Restart the Service. If it is not, change them now.

Option B:
If your bluetooth continues to have this problem it could be driver related.

1. At this point it is important to make sure all of your windows updates are turned on as we will need them to re-install the bluetooth driver. To check this go to start menu, search 'windows update'. In Windows Update select always check for update if it is not already selected.
2. From the start menu search 'Device Manager' once in device manager locate your bluetooth device from the devices menu and uninstall the driver. When prompted select uninstall software.
3. Your PC should now reboot and windows update will download and install the bluetooth driver.